# how does pandas access read_csv when the entire path isn't mentioned?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pretty new to Python and I am trying to understand how import works. I have a doubt when it comes to `read_csv.`

We generally use the following lines when we call the read_csv function.

```
import pandas as pd
...
...
file=pd.read_csv(Filename)
```

The read_csv module is present in the module pandas.io.parsers. Why don't we mention the entire path before accessing read_csv? I mean, why not this:

```
import pandas.io.parsers as pd
...
...
file=pd.read_csv(Filename)
```

If we can access a function without giving the entire path, why do we use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
...
plt.show()
```

when we can just write

```
import matplotlib as plt
...
...
plt.show()
```

What I mean to ask is, are the imports used in Python codes just conventions(is the .pyplot tacked on to `matplotlib.pyplot` omissible?) or are there specific rules? Do we use the entire location when there's a chance of clash with other methods of the same name? Do modules in a package contain non-unique function names then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on whether the package chooses to expose some of the "deeper" functions to the package namespace. This is done through a file called `__init__.py`. This gives flexibility, because it allows the developer to keep chunks of the source code organized in multiple folders, but easily accessible by the user importing the package as a whole.

This also means that the "rules" for importing - whether you import `matplotlib` or `matplotlib.pyplot` - depend on the package's maintainers. Both `matplotlib` and `matplotlib.pyplot` are considered packages, because they each have a `__init.py` file associated with their respective folder in the source code. What you exactly you import by writing `import matplotlib` or `import matplotlib.pyplot` depends on the contents of these `__init__.py` files.

For example, you can see in the [pandas source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/__init__.py) that there is a filled called `__init__.py` at the source root, meaning it will import some names whenever you `import pandas` in your code. It includes the import for `read_csv` at around line 150:

```
from pandas.io.api import (
# ...
read_csv, 
# ...
)
```

Comment: Apologies, I have a couple of doubts.(1)"it allows the developer to keep chunks of the source code organized in multiple folders..." You mean to say that read_csv's code is present in __init__.py while the rest of the api module's source code is at a different place? (2) As long as there's an __init__.py file, can any "folder" be labelled a package? (3) Can the __init__.py file be used to import anything? Classes, sub-packages, functions..? (4) Noob question, what's a namespace, in non-technical terms?

Comment: 1) it's the other way around, only the import of read_csv is present in the pandas `__init__.py`, the actual code responsible for parsing a csv file is located in `pandas.io.parsers`, which is in turn imported by `pandas.io.api`... Navigate the source code on github to see it for yourself. 2) yes (having a `__init__.py` is what *defines* a package). 3) yes. 4) it's everything associated with a given "name", for example the pandas namespace includes everything that you can access with `pd. ...` after you import the namespace by writing `import pandas as pd`.